# how to resize an image and make it smooth like original

Tags: php, html, image-resizing

i have an image which width is 213 and height is 200 when i echo the image from my database and i resize it `(echo "<img src='company/$present' width='70' height='68'/>";)` the image was not as clear as when it was 213 * 200. how can i make the image smooth like the original after i have resize it to 70 * 68 or rather when i increase above 213 * 200.

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM photo";
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die('query error');
    $count = 0;
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $image = $line[picname];
    echo "<img src='company/$image'/> ";
    $count++;
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: Have you considered creating and storing thumbnails of the image? Right now you're just echoing the image tag and php isn't doing anything with the image.

Answer (score 2):

> how can i make the image smooth like the original after i have resize it to 70 * 68 or rather when i increase above 213 * 200.

Internet Explorer in particular seems to use a nasty algorithm for sizing images down. You'd be best off using a toolkit like ImageMagick or PHP's GD to size the image on the server-side.

Nothing's going to make upscaling look good.

Answer (score 2):

Add the CSS tag `img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }` to choose smoother resizing in Internet Explorer 7. IE8 already uses this by default. I don't remember if it works in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule don't set both the width and the height explicitly for the image.  It becomes very difficult to maintain the aspect ratio of the image that way.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to keep the images aspect ration, so basically if the image was 800 x 1200 , instead of resizing it to a certain pixel size do it by percent and make sure the width and height are being changed by the same percent.